# Make FeatureClass that has a FileGeodatabase data source editable?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, file-geodatabase, feature-layer

I wasn't able to find any documentation on this, but is it possible to use the Editor widget in the [Esri JS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/editor-amd.html) to edit a FeatureLayer whose data source is that's stored in a FileGeodatabase?

I've tried using the widget to select and delete a feature, but nothing happens and there's no errors in the JS console.

I found a post on [another forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=206&f=2422&t=275451) suggesting it's not possible, but I didn't find any supporting documentation:

> A feature layer can be editable if:
>
> 1. Your feature class (FC) data source is SDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a read - [Editing](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_editing.html)

> The ArcGIS Web APIs provide simple feature editing. The features must
>   come from an ArcSDE geodatabase. This geodatabase can be licensed for
>   either workgroup or enterprise use and does not have to be versioned.

Comment: And I can confirm that ArcMap (10.1SP1 in my case) just won't let you publish a FeatureService for a layer from a FGDB. I tried that recently and *then* noticed the above fine print! Pesky ESRI ;-)